# google hangouts api unable to fire events

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-hangouts

I'm quite in confusion in using `Google Hangouts API`.
I've gone through the API [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) and have created the project and followed the steps given in the second step.
I've a requirement where user will `initiate a hangout` and `send the link` to some of the people and people can `join` in it.

Let's consider the sample app [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps).
How can I make use of the `Gadget XML` and `Source Code` in my `MVC` application and start a Hangout?

They have given a sample XML file which contains some html code also.

How can I call that XML file in my application and be able to fire some of the events of hangouts like `getHangoutUrl()`?

Answer (score 0):

- **Initiate a hangout** : [Hangout Button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) is what you are looking for, you just need to add required javascript files to your page and use 'gapi.hangout.render' to render the button on your page.
- **Send out hangout link to others** : you can use the invite option where you can add invites(email, gplus profile_id, phone no.) while rendering the hangout button, more info and examples [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#basic_page_with_profile_and_e-mail_invites).
- **Gadget XML file** : This file should to be hosted on your server on some public url which doesn't need any kind of authentication.
  You can add your scripts, styles and html to be rendered on hangout app server more info [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/publishing#application-url).
- **Handling events in hangout app** : Well you can use ajax to post changes in hangout app to your server. But it would be better if you use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) to take care of hangout triggered events(onYouTubeLiveIdReady, onParticipantsAdded etc.) asynchronously and push changes to clients.
  You can also use it to add chat messages feature to your app using it, so that viewers can also interact with the hangout participants incase of Hoa broadcast.